# The Schema Compare tool in Visual Studio has stopped working properly, giving "cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'DbName'" errors

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-comparison

Full Error:

> Error  1   SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\TestSource.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'TestSource'.    SchemaCompare3  25  0

Irrespective which database connection\files I am using. I even created two new databases to test with simple one table, once column and it gives the same error.

I have used the tool before with no problems. All of the sudden it's not working anymore.

Any suggestions on how to fix it would be great. I have seen numerous posts about this error, but none fit my scenario where absolutely no two source and target db's will work.

Also problem may possibly lie in the `.\SQLEXPRESS` engine.